# How can I rotate a sphere preserving one meridian?

Tags: python, numpy, geometry

This is for latitude/longitude on Earth, so I'll use those terms, but I'm interested in a spherical-Earth approximation, no need for fancy geodesy, just trigonometry. I'm fine dealing with (ρ, θ, φ) as well.

What I want to do is take one point `(lat, lon)` and rotate the sphere so that:

1. `(lat, lon)` becomes `(0, 0)`.
2. The `lon` meridian becomes the new prime meridian (the old north and south poles should appear on the great circle of 0 / 180 longitude, at latitudes offset from +/- 90 by `lat`).

I need to be able to take any other point on the sphere and compute where it will end up after this rotation — or, if it would be easier to find the x, y, z coordinates of the transformed point, without ever producing the transformed latitude/longitude, that's fine too.

I think this is a simple composition of two rotations — one about the axis through the poles, by `-lon`, and one about an axis that passes through the equator at `lon ± 90°`, by `-lat`, but I'm not sure on that and I'm stumbling on the math.

Comment: Any time you have to do anything in spherical coordinates anywhere around (0,0), you'll be best off using quaternions, lest your calculations end up in the hell that is gimbal lock.   You probably want to ask a math stack how convert lat/long to a quaternion, and then your answer will just be the inverse of that quaternion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've pretty much got it.  I'll talk about the Cartesian transform. If you want to stay with spherical coordinates, quaternions are the way to go as others have said.

Assume the origin is at the center of the earth, the x-axis pokes out on the prime meridian at the equator and the y-axis pokes out at the north pole. Then for a right hand coordinate system the z-axis will poke out on the equator at -90 degrees.

Getting "lon" to the x-y plane requires rotating by -lon about the y-axis.  Then getting lat down to the equator requires rotating again by -lat.

You can use 3d affine transforms to represent these:

```
           [ cos(-lon)  0   sin(-lon) ]   [ cos(lon)  0   -sin(lon) ]
Ry(-lon) = [ 0          1   0         ] = [ 0         1   0         ]
           [-sin(-lon)  0   cos(-lon) ]   [ sin(lon)  0   cos(lon)  ]

           [ cos(-lat)  -sin(-lat)   0 ]   [ cos(lat)  sin(lat)   0 ]
Rz(-lat) = [ sin(-lat)   cos(-lat)   0 ] = [-sin(lat)  cos(lat)   0 ]
           [  0          0           1 ]   [  0        0          1 ]
```

The transform you want is T(p) = Rz * (Ry * p).  That is, apply the y rotation to p and the z rotation to that result.

But by matrix multiplication's associativity, we can say this is equal to (Rz * Ry) * p. That is, we can multiply the matrices once and use the resulting compound rotation on as many points as we like.

Doing this multiplication produces:

```
[ cos(lat) cos(lon)    sin(lat)   -cos(lat) sin(lon) ]
[-cos(lon) sin(lat)    cos(lat)    sin(lat) sin(lon) ]
[ sin(lon)             0           cos(lon)          ]
```

Let's check whether this actually works.  The (x,y,z) coordinate of (lat,lon) - assuming the earth has unit radius - is

```
x =  cos(lat) cos(lon)
y =  sin(lat)
z = -cos(lat) sin(lon)
```

Multiplying by the matrix above, we get

```
x = cos^2(lat) cos^2(lon) + sin^2(lat) + cos^2(lat) sin^2(lon) = 1
y = -cos^2(lon) sin(lat) cos(lat) + cos(lat) sin(lat) - cos(lat) sin^2(lon) sin(lat) = 0
z = sin(lon) cos(lat) cos(lon) - cos(lat) sin(lon) cos(lon) = 0
```

I plugged these into Wolfram Alpha to verify.

So it seems to be working fine.  In other words, to transform any other point (x, y, z) on the sphere, just find

```
A = cos(lat) cos(lon)
B = sin(lat)
C = -cos(lat) sin(lon)
D = -cos(lon) sin(lat)
E = cos(lat)
F = -sin(lat) sin(lon)
G = sin(lon)
H = cos(lon)
```

one time. Then transform with

```
x' =  A x + B y + C z
y' =  D x + E y + F z
z' =  G x       + H z
```

as many times as needed.

nb: Even with the one successful check, please verify the math. It's been a looong day.